# FrozenError when creating new Watir Browser

Tags: ruby, string, watir

I'm trying to open a new `Watir::Browser` on a Heroku machine

The instruction I am giving is

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

But this is throwing me an exception

`FrozenError (can't modify frozen String)`

I must assume this is a ruby 2.6 issue

Comment: There is an issue in Watir's github (https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/877) the errors are ocurring in several places and it looks like a Ruby 2.6 issue. 
I will downgrade ruby for the sake of moving forwards for now.

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.6 with recent watir but I don't have any such issue.

Comment: Maybe it is because your code can find firefox, mine was unaccessible from the code and thus an exception was tried to be thrown and it fell in that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that firefox is not installed or not being found?  There's a [known bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7365) for Webdriver will generate an error like this if you are on a newer version of Ruby and it can't locate the firefox executable.   (all of which might change in the future when that issue is addressed)

if you read the issue, it's trying to do some magic with strings for the error message, but also wanting to use frozen strings, and thus the error (can't have it both ways)

Comment: Yes, finally that is the issue. It breaks while trying to show up the problem.